# checking password character length in php

Tags: php

I am trying to check the password length a user enters in a registration form.
but I am getting an unexpected output.Here is my script.

```
 <?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
  {

  if(strlen(trim($password)) > 8)
   {
   echo"Password must be 8characters";
   }
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: And the unexpected output is... ?

Comment: Why would you limit the password to an 8 character maximum?

Comment: What happens with this code? Please mention precisely. It's quite unclear with your text - "*I am getting an unexpected output*".

Comment: In my registration form, I am also checking that an email field is not empty and that validates perfectly.However,when I add the password length check script, the email script is rather fired

Comment: you also should not `trim()` or otherwise alter the given password in *any* way. If the user wants to use whitespace characters in their password, then so much the better.

Answer (score 9):

Your code fails because the variable `$password` is never assigned any value. You're then checking to see if the password is **longer** than 8 characters--you're using a greater-than symbol instead of less-than. Since the variable `$password` is empty, the check for length greater-than 8 is always false.

Try this:

```
if(!array_key_exists('password', $_POST))
    die('no password specified');

$password = trim($_POST['password']); // <--- this is not a good idea!
if(strlen($password) < 8)
    die('Password must be at least 8 characters');
```

To recap, the unexpected output is caused by two factors:

- wrong comparison operator
- empty variable

You should certainly do something more user-friendly than `die`, in production code.

**Documentation**

- `$_POST` - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
- `strlen` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php
- `array_key_exists` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
- Comparison operators - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- variables - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: It's possible the OP has `register_globals` on

Comment: I chose to ignore that possibility. None the less, the logical error in the code prevents even register_globals from saving the day (for the first time ever)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should rather use `$_POST['password']`, using automatic globals is wrong (and hopefully disabled on many hostings).

Also limiting password to 8 characters looks like a bad idea, you should hash it anyway and the length does not matter then.